# Автоматический старт домена при запуске GlassFish

Tags: glassfish, windows-server

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при запуске GlassFish автоматически стартовал домен (start-domain). GlassFish стоит на Windows Server. Запускается батником.

Comment: Упс... Даже стыдно теперь немного ) В папке Bin оказывается есть батник startserv, который всё это запускает. А я пытался дописать команду start-domain в файл asadmin.
Так что всем спасибо. Уже не актуально )